# Create class having django's inner Meta class using type() method

Tags: python, django

I'm working on function (in Django 1.4, python 2.7.2+) that generates the Form for specified Model and returns it.
I've got trouble using type() method with 3 arguments, because I want to specify Form's inner Meta class. Django documentation gives an example of auto-generated Form for Model:

```
class PartialAuthorForm
    m(ModelForm):
        class Meta:
            model = Author
```

Now I want to generalize it and make forms automatically. So I want to specify Meta inside returned Form, and attribute "model = model_cls" in it.

```
from django.forms import ModelForm
def generate_form_for(model_cls):
    ret_cls = type(model_cls.__name__ + "Form", (ModelForm,), {???})
```

I don't know what "???" should be replaced with. Do you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've solved this by doing something like this:

```
Meta = type('Meta', (), {                                                   
    'model': ExampleModel,                                                                                                           
})                                                                                                                                                           

ExampleForm = type('ExampleForm', (), {                                                                             
    'Meta': Meta,                                                                                                              
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Check how Django `modelform_factory` works:

https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/forms/models.py#L372

`Meta` is class attribute.